# (window).scroll(function() в js

Tags: javascript, прокрутка

Добрый день!

Перейду сразу к описанию вопроса.

Создана страница при помощи wordpress, которая при слишком длинном тексте разворачивается для полноценного просмотра (скролл вниз и разворот). Проблема в том, что при слишком длинном тексте она начинает дёргаться и не прокручивается до конца. Спасает только `&nbsp;` в конце текста в количестве 2-3 штуки. Однако же есть идея применить что-то более удобное на js. **Вопрос только - что подойдёт для решения проблемы с применением ниже указанного кода?**

Пробовалось в Opera и Mozzila, Google Chrome и IE. Чисто, без дёрганий, получилось только на IE.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var block_btn = $(".b_fix");
  var offset = block_btn.offset();
  if (offset.top <= 1100) {
    $("#lc").removeClass('hide-l');
    $("#rc").removeClass('full-r');
  } else {
    $("#lc").addClass('hide-l');
    $("#rc").addClass('full-r');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дам тебе совет все равно в рамках jQuery, потому как, я почти уверен, что дело у тебя вовсе не в "корявости" его функций, а в чем-то другом, а, стало быть, реализация без jQuery приведет тебя к тем же результатам.

Вообще, трудно рассуждать, не видя живого примера, но, вот что уже сразу бросается в глаза, так это ряд не очень хороших вещей в самой ф-ции:

`$(window).scroll(function() {});` срабатывает *каждый раз* при скроле:: т.е. у тебя при каждом скролле выполняется дофига ф-ций, часть из которых тебе не нужна на самом деле вовсе, часть - возвращает всякий раз один и тот же результат, часть - пытается многократно повторить одно и тоже: например, у тебя при каждой прокрутке колеса мыши вызывается объект $("#lc") блока #lc и ему пытается присвоить класс 'hide-l' (при каждом скроле!) (к стати, вполне м.б. одной из причин дергания - что у тебя поочередно начинает срабатывать то то то это - можешь посмотреть через console.log();)
Во вторых, я так понял `block_btn = $(".b_fix"); block_btn.offset().top` - это какой-то фиксированый блок внизу экрана по которому ты хочешь определить низ экрана? Это можно сделать при помощи `$(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();` - порой может корректнее сработать. В общем, эти вещи могут и давать пляску

Могу предложить тебе вот такой вариант, который, как мне кажется, будет работать лучше:

```
 var $win = $(window);//Функция  $(window); возвращает объект, причем, каждый раз один и тот же - так что, получаем 1 раз и полно выносим за пределы. 
 var winHeight = $win.height();//сразу получим высоту окна браузера
 $win.resize(function(){winHeight = $win.height();});//Это чтобы избежать глюков, если изменился размер окна браузера - $(window).resize();
 var ststus = 'свернут';//Чтобы избежать повторного вызова функций - по умолчанию, будем считать эту штуку свернутой

var $lc = $("#lc"), $rc = $("#rc");//Опять же, чтобы по сто раз не запрашивать одно и то же

 var hAct = 1100;//Твоя высота активации... вынессюда, т.к. не понимаю, почему именно 1100 - такие штуки порой, мне кажется, лучше все-таки получать программно через всякие там offcet и height

 $win.scroll(function() { 
    var winBottom = $win.scrollTop() + winHeight;//Получаем низ окна браузера; $(window).scrollTop() - получает, соотв. верх (кажется, она так же его и назначать умеет, но не помню уже - редко пользуюсь)
   if (ststus == 'свернут' && winBottom > hAct) {//Разворачивается
   //Сработает только если свернут
     $lc.addClass('hide-l');
     $rc.addClass('full-r');  
     ststus = 'развернут';//Меняем статус
   } else if (ststus == 'развернут' && winBottom < (hAct-50)) {//Сворачивается обратно (не знаю, зачем тебе это, но пусть будет)
    //Сработает только если развернут; hAct-50 - 50px погоды не сделают, но, если у тебя в результате твоих манипуляций что-то хоть на пиксель сместилось, чтобы тут же не сработала обратная ф-ция; 50 - взято от балды, с погрешностью можно и поэксперементировать
     $lc.removeClass('hide-l');
     $rc.removeClass('full-r');
     ststus = 'свернут';//Меняем снова статус
}
});
```

что до   - подозреваю, что где-то неправильно определяешь высоту (не забывай, про такие милые вещи, как всякие margin'ы, padding'и  и прочие маленькие радости - height(), innerHeight(), outerHeight(), outerHeight(true)... - возможно, где-то здесь у тебя засада..

Comment: прошу прощения, что долго не отвечала. Сегодня попробую применить код на практике. По возможности, я могу к вам обращаться за помощью по некоторым вопросам? На шею садиться не буду, обещаю :)

Comment: код не принёс желаемого результата, но в одном вы точно были правы - `hAct = 1100;` - поменяла на 1000 и всё стало совершенно спокойно во всех браузерах открываться. Спасибо, спасибо и ещё раз спасибо, что засомневались в высоте активации.

Comment: Как говориться, "а ларчик-то просто открывался"))
Да, коненечно, если надо - обращайтесь если что